# Problem with replacing componentWillReceiveProps with static getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have `Dropdown` comp, in which user can select some filters.

Also I have buttons `clear-filters`, when user click on that button filters are gone in parent component, but in the `dropdown comp` is still stayed selected filters.

That means my dropdown is not updated properly as before with `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`:

Dropdown component with `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`:

```
  state = {
     options: props.options || []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setSelectedOptions(this.props);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
    if (this.props.onRef) {
      this.props.onRef(this);
    }
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setSelectedOptions(props);
  }
```

This is Dropdown migrate version which does not work as before:

```
  state = {
      options: props.options || []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setSelectedOptions(this.props);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
    if (this.props.onRef) {
      this.props.onRef(this);
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const { options } = nextProps;

// CHECKING DOES SOME OPTIONS PROPERTIES ARE CHANGED OR NOT
    options.forEach((filter, i) => {
      if (filter.selected !== prevState.options[i].selected) {
        return { options };
      }
    });
    return null;
  }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick inspection it seems like the only issue here is that you are returning 'options' from the wrong place. Note that when you use forEach on the array, you are passing a function which is executed with each element of the array. When you return { options }, you are only returning from the function passed to forEach, and not actually from getDerivedStateFromProps.

I would suggest instead creating a flag variable (shouldReturnOptions) in the scope of getDerivedStateFromProps:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  const { options } = nextProps;
  let shouldReturnOptions = false;

  options.forEach((filter, i) => {
    if ((!shouldReturnOptions) && (filter.selected !== prevState.options[i].selected)) {
      shouldReturnOptions = true;
    }
  });

  if (shouldReturnOptions) {
    return { options };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you on your answer and time. 
Problem is still active, but this answer was helpful!

Comment: @MichelJames Great, let me know when you've managed to solve to remaining issue, I'd be interested to know what was wrong!